# Is it possible to return tensorflow code from compiled Keras model?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'll start this post by saying that I acknowledge this may not be the appropriate venue for this question, but wasn't sure where else to start. If there is a more appropriate SE channel, please feel free to suggest.

I've been using Keras for learning how to apply neural networks to different prediction problems. I'm interested in learning TensorFlow as a way to gain a deeper understanding of the inner working of these networks. Obviously, it's possible to switch the backend of Keras to TensorFlow and to use Keras as a high-level API to TensorFlow. However, is there a way to "recover" the TensorFlow code from a compiled Keras model? I'm thinking it would be extremely useful to be able to write a model that I'm familiar with in Keras, and automatically see it's "translation" to TensorFlow as a way to learn this library more quickly.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

All that Keras is doing is to abstract both Theano and TensorFlow into one unified backend module. Then it uses the functions in the backend to implement the layers and methods you are able to use in Keras.

This in turn means that there is no compilation step involved in generating code for one particular backend. Both Theano and TensorFlow are python libraries, there is no reason for a translation step, Keras just uses the library you specify.

The best way to find out how a model in Keras is written in TensorFlow is probably to search for a simple network with the same dataset and compare examples in TensorFlow and Keras. Another way would be to read the Keras code and lookup the `K.<function>` in the TensorFlow backend module.

If you are interested in the platform specific code that the individual backends produce, e.g. the CUDA code, then the answer is: it depends. Both Theano and TensorFlow use temporary directories to store the code and the sources. For theano this is `~/.theano` by default. But looking at this code will probably not make you any wiser in understanding neural networks and their mechanics.